# Rounding time with intervals in php

Tags: php, time

I want to convert times to rounded times.
Therefore I **only** want to use intervals in seconds.
It works well for quarter hours and full hours. But not for days. Then it is messed up. But I can't understand why

This is my function:

```
function formatToMySQLTime($sTime,$iInterval){
    switch ($iInterval){
        case 1: // 15 minutes;
            $iDivider = 15 * 60;
            break;
        case 2: // 1 hour
            $iDivider = 60 * 60;
            break;
        case 3: // 1 day
            $iDivider = 60 * 60 * 24;
            break;
    }    
    $iRemainder = strtotime($sTime) % $iDivider;
    $iRoundTime = strtotime($sTime) - $iRemainder;    
    $sTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $iRoundTime);
    return $sTime;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
echo formatToMySQLTime('2013-10-21 03:23:00',1);
2013-10-21 03:15:00

echo formatToMySQLTime('2013-10-21 03:23:00',2);
2013-10-21 03:00:00

echo formatToMySQLTime('2013-10-21 03:23:00',3);
2013-10-21 02:00:00
```

The third output is wrong, it should be `2013-10-21 00:00:00`. What is my mistake?

Comment: The first output is wrong, isn't it? Shouldn't it be `2013-10-21 00:01:45`?

Comment: Then it should be `00:02:00`

Comment: Never mind, I was confusing minutes and seconds.

Comment: It's a time zone issue, but I'm not sure why it only affects the last case.

Comment: @PeterI:  3rd-one is returning `2013-10-22 00:00:00`; see [here](https://eval.in/58316). You are having timezone issues, see [here](https://eval.in/58317). And why must `2013-10-21 00:01:48` become `2013-10-21 00:00:00`? Should't it be 22nd day?

Comment: Try add date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta'); //your time zone try again. Beacuse the above code works for me correctly.

Comment: @Glavić You are right. I will correct my topic

Comment: I don't recommend `strtotime` and uses the timezone settings, try using [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) whenever possible.

Comment: @vijay4vijju When using "Asia/Calcutta" it outputs: 2013-10-20 05:30:00

Comment: @Barmar isn't it daylight saving affecting?

Comment: @bansi No, it's more than that. I tried it here, and I got `20:00:00` because I'm 4 hours behind GMT.

Comment: Try using `date_default_timezone_set('GMT');`. Don't forget it back to your original settings after use.

Comment: @PeterI , vijay4vijju is right it's about your default_timezone. If you want 0, try to use Europe/London for example.

Comment: It has to be a timezone issue, but I already set my timezone. And it is outputting the right timezone. @bansi Please provide an working example with DateTime::createFromFormat  ... so I can accept it as an answer.

Comment: It gives me wrong result for even the second option. I am at timezone +5:30. Result:`2013-10-21 03:15:00`, `2013-10-21 02:30:00`, `2013-10-20 05:30:00`. and with `date_default_timezone_set('GMT');` the result:`2013-10-21 03:15:00`, `2013-10-21 03:00:00`, `2013-10-21 00:00:00`

Comment: @PeterI: you can even use [this function](https://eval.in/58330), where the seconds parameter is more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have timezone issue, because `strtotime` function is not timezone aware, and `date` is. Instead of setting global timezone, you can set it locally with appending  `UTC` string to the `$sTime` variable, and instead of using `date()` use `gmdate()`:

```
// it doesn't matter in which timezone your are, function works with UTC
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');

function formatToMySQLTime($sTime, $iInterval) {
    switch ($iInterval){
        case 1: // 15 minutes;
            $iDivider = 15 * 60;
            break;
        case 2: // 1 hour
            $iDivider = 60 * 60;
            break;
        case 3: // 1 day
            $iDivider = 60 * 60 * 24;
            break;
    }
    $U = strtotime($sTime . ' UTC');
    $iRoundTime = $U - $U % $iDivider;    
    return gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', $iRoundTime);
}
    
echo formatToMySQLTime('2013-10-21 03:23:00',1);
echo formatToMySQLTime('2013-10-21 03:23:00',2);
echo formatToMySQLTime('2013-10-21 03:23:00',3);
```

**[Run code](https://eval.in/58326).**

---

## Update:

Instead of modifying function for every interval, you can **make function a little more generic and readable**, with the help of [DateTime classes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php), like:

```
function formatToMySQLTime($sTime, $iInterval) {
    $dt = new DateTime($sTime, new DateTimezone('UTC'));
    $U = $dt->getTimestamp();

    $dt2 = clone $dt;
    $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString($iInterval);
    $iDivider = $dt2->add($interval)->getTimestamp() - $U;
    
    $dt->setTimestamp($U - $U % $iDivider);
    return $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}

echo formatToMySQLTime('2013-10-21 03:23:00', '15 minute');
echo formatToMySQLTime('2013-10-21 03:23:00', '1 hour');
echo formatToMySQLTime('2013-10-21 03:23:00', '1 day');
```

[**Run code**](https://eval.in/58330).

Answer (score 0):

> What is my mistake?

The whole approach is flawed.

If you check your `$iRemainder`, you’ll see it contains a date value like `Thu, 01 Jan 1970 23:01:48 +0100` – and subtracting that from your original value and adding “a days worth of seconds” again of course gets messy with the different times caused by DST.

When working with unix timestamps, assuming a day would always consist of a certain amount of seconds is just plain wrong – *because* of things like DST.

Btw., you are not actually “rounding”, based on your examples – for the first two, you are rounding *up* to the next 15 minutes or full hour, but for the third one you want to round *down* to the day – what’s the logic behind that?

I’d suggest you look at the necessary parts of the date individually, and then return a formated date with the rest just set to matching value manually.

Comment: I'm checking `$iRemainder` and it tells me it's an integer value. 
And I'm not rounding up, I'm rounding down. Please check my post.

Comment: Of course it’s an integer value – but the _meaning_ of that integer value _as a timestamp_ is different from what you assume. And for the rounding thing – well if you _change_ your post after I answered …